# Pocket Base Update using Python Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, database, pocketbase

```
import requests
import json
import openai

def update_db(question_id,generated_ans2):
    patch_url="/api/collections/question/records/:"+question_id
    
    data={
        generated_ans:generated_ans2,
    }
    data=json.dumps(data)

    response=requests.patch(base_url+patch_url,json=data)
    if response.status_code==200:
        print("Data Inserted Succesfully")

    else:
        print("Failed to insert")
        print(response.text)
```

Here, question_id is an integer and the question collection has other fields too, but i just want to update this field.